# Auto-read .egg zip archive

Tags: plugin-zip

Vim can read / write a gzipped file [like this](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#gzip-example) which is great but it only works with gunzip, because it can read from stdin. Apparently zip files have a directory listing at the end of the archive which makes this difficult.

I'm working with zipped Python .egg files (for those who don't know, .egg is a zipped Python format). When I get Python tracebacks which refer to a .egg location, for example this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/foo/bar.egg/dir/file.py", line 15, in main
ValueError: asdf
```

I can literally replace "/foo/bar.egg/dir/file.py" with "zipfile:/foo/bar.egg::dir/file.py" and then run `:e zipfile:/foo/bar.egg::dir/file.py` and Vim will open the zipped file correctly. It opens with read/write access through, for whatever reason, I get an exception "Undefined variable: s:zipfile_1" in `zip#Write` any time I `:w`.

I made a script that automates doing this substitution on each line and then runs that code through `:set makeprg=converted_text` `:make` but I'd like to ask:

1. Can I somehow get Vim to detect a .egg and convert "/foo/bar.egg/dir/file.py" to "zipfile:/foo/bar.egg::dir/file.py" automatically on file read without me having to do manual effort?
2. Can this suggested idea for #1 modify the file in-place with read/write access?

In regards to #1, I tried using BufReadPre/BufReadPost but Vim gave me warnings about being allowed to modify the current buffer.

Comment: you might be able to work off this example, which is similar for handling filename:linenumber https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lervag/file-line/master/plugin/file_line.vim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented at `:help zip-extension`, you may use the following

```
augroup zip_add
   au!
   au BufReadCmd *.egg call zip#Browse(expand("<amatch>"))
augroup END
```

Comment: This is what I needed to find. It only works if I read the .egg directly but I will try changing it to `au BufReadCmd *.py` and "detecting" if the parent path is a .egg to get me the same result. I will mark as accepted if that works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't really address the question which is "redirect filenames"

Comment: The example posted here is basically 50% of what I needed. After running zip#Browse, you still have to select the file in the listing. I made a script that does this automatically, using the path from the traceback. So I'll mark this answer as correct. Thanks again!